# Encode image to send it to a server

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

i am trying to encode a image to a server, because if i just send it, the server tells me, i shouldn't upload a empty image.

In the formdata i can see the image was converted to a binary file
[image: Form data]

In PyCharm i see this "apprent_encoding", and i think the image hast to be encoded to ISO-8859-9, but how can i do this? I just find tutorials to encode a image to base64...

[image: Pycharm]

My Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

header = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36'}
header['content-type'] = 'text/html'

base_url = 'https://www.ebay-kleinanzeigen.de/'

session = requests.session()
res = BeautifulSoup(session.get(f'{base_url}m-einloggen.html').content, 'lxml')
csrf_token = res.find('input', {'name': '_csrf'})['value']
print(f'Found token: {csrf_token}')

payload = dict()
payload['targetUrl'] = '/'
payload['loginMail'] = 'testaccount@8.dnsabr.com'
payload['password'] = 'testaccount'
payload['_csrf'] = csrf_token
payload['fingerprint'] = '4dd6ba9367ddc34f0b00cf9566e01b63'

res = session.post(f'{base_url}m-einloggen.html', data=payload, allow_redirects=True)
print(f'Logged in: {res.status_code}')

img_file = open(r'C:\Users\Oli\Downloads\IF\1.jpg', 'rb')

files = {'name': 'TestImg.jpg', 'file': ('TestImg.jpg', img_file, 'image/jpeg', {'Expires': '10'})}

header['content-type'] = 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----moxieboundary1563218428568'
header['x-csrf-token'] = csrf_token
res = session.post(f'{base_url}p-bild-hochladen.html', headers=header, files=files)
print(f'Image uploaded: {res.status_code}')
uploaded_image_name = json.loads(res.content.decode('utf-8'))['fileName']
# print(f'New Link: https://pasteboard.co/{uploaded_image_name}')
```

Comment: if you send empty image then maybe you send it in wrong way and encoding may not change it. Better show code, url to server and describe API used by server - or add url to documentation.

Comment: I just added my code, this is how i send the image. I open the image and send it in binary, but the server thinks its empty. Please check my code, the login creditals are working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code works for me if I remove both `header['content-type']`

`requests` should set this header correctly on its own.

And I display all JSON data because there is no field `'fileName'` but status is `'OK'` and there are urls to images in different sizes.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

header = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36'}
#header['content-type'] = 'text/html'

base_url = 'https://www.ebay-kleinanzeigen.de/'

session = requests.session()
res = BeautifulSoup(session.get(f'{base_url}m-einloggen.html').content, 'lxml')
csrf_token = res.find('input', {'name': '_csrf'})['value']
print(f'Found token: {csrf_token}')

payload = dict()
payload['targetUrl'] = '/'
payload['loginMail'] = 'testaccount@8.dnsabr.com'
payload['password'] = 'testaccount'
payload['_csrf'] = csrf_token
payload['fingerprint'] = '4dd6ba9367ddc34f0b00cf9566e01b63'

res = session.post(f'{base_url}m-einloggen.html', data=payload, allow_redirects=True)
print(f'Logged in: {res.status_code}')

img_file = open(r'C:\Users\Oli\Downloads\IF\1.jpg', 'rb')

files = {'name': 'TestImg.jpg', 'file': ('TestImg.jpg', img_file, 'image/jpeg', {'Expires': '10'})}

#header['content-type'] = 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----moxieboundary1563218428568'
header['x-csrf-token'] = csrf_token
res = session.post(f'{base_url}p-bild-hochladen.html', headers=header, files=files)
print(f'Image uploaded: {res.status_code}')
uploaded_image_name = json.loads(res.content.decode('utf-8'))#['fileName']
print(uploaded_image_name)
# print(f'New Link: https://pasteboard.co/{uploaded_image_name}')
```

Comment: Wow thank you mate, could you tell me why its now working?

Comment: because `requests` creates header `'content-type'` on its own and it makes it better :)  With your `'content-type'` it treated it as normal data, not file. If you use `session.post("http://httpbin.org/post, headers=header, files=files)` then server sends you back information what it gets and you will see if it get it as file or normal data. Using local proxy server like [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/) you could even see raw request and see difference between reuqest send from browser and from your code.

Comment: you can also use `print(res.request.headers)` and `print(res.request.body)` to see that `reuqests` creates body with own boundary number which is different then bundary number in your `'content-type'` and then server doesn't recognize it as file. If you don't use own `'content-type'` then requests use the same boundary number in both places.